# Why people mixed ASP.Net MVC and web-api in same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i need few reason for which people mixed ASP.Net MVC and web-api in same project. when we can develop a full project in mvc only then why web api need to include. also we can host webapi project separately which can server request to MVC and other devs or mobile devs etc.discuss the reason and advantages.

### some one answer :

We have recently built a project within MVC and WebApi, we used the WebApi purely because from a Mobile Apps perspective.  We allowed the mobile dev guys to call our methods within our MVC application instead of them having to go and create the same function.

WebApi allows to create services that can be exposed over HTTP rather than through a formal service such as WCF or SOAP. Another difference is in the way how WebApi uses Http protocol and makes it truly First class Http citizen.

still the above answer is not clear to me and i think this is not the reason for which people mixed ASP.Net MVC and web-api in same project.

so anyone mind to discuss the actual reason and advantages with example scenario.
thanks

Comment: same reason people mix ui and biz logic and data layer.  not doing "separation of concerns" and/or laziness.

Comment: people can have biz and dal layer in model folder or in separate class reside in other folder. then why some one use webapi for this.....does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Each have a purpose.  Most of the time it's usually caused by legacy code.  I know we included documentation which used MVC, but we're fully webapi.

FYI, was MS's auto documentation for WebApi ironically.

Comment: not very clear what u try to say.......better to discuss with example scenario in details. thanks